# ASP.NET InnerXml automatically/incorrectly appending attribute text to tags

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, .net-2.0

So I have some XML in the following format:

```
<somenode>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>P one</p>
            <p>Another p</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</somenode>
```

Nestled in there is some html, which I didn't think would be an issue as it would just be treated as xml.

I'm trying to select the contents (InnerXml) of the <body> tag. However, using

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("somenode/html/body")
```

returns `null`, and using

```
xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].InnerXml
```

gives the InnerXml - but each <p> has `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` appended to it - so the result looks like:

```
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">P one</p><p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Another p</p>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Seems like some really weird behavior, any help would be appreciated. I'm only using ASP.net 2.0, so unfortunately trying linq isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath expression isn't specifying the default namespace.  How about:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("somenode/xhtml:html/xhtml:body", nsMgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<html>` element defines the default namespace to be http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. All elements inside it without a namespace prefix have the same namespace by default.

Since the content of the body tag is 2 separate `<p>` elements, they both get the declaration. If you had other elements inside your `<p>` elements, they will not have the declaration on them.